# Не срабатывает обработчик события click (обьекты на страницу добавлены не динамически)

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Здравствуйте, хелп !
 Вывожу на страницу вот такие блоки с иконками:

```
<div id="itemIcon" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
   <i id="icon" class="fa fa-area-chart fa-2x"></i> 
</div>
```

---

вешаю на них обработчик события:

```
$('#itemIcon').click(function(event){
  alert(event.type);
});
```

При нажатии на див с id="itemIcon" ничего не происходит, не могу понять причину... Обьекты на страницу добавлены нединамически, В консоли какие либо ошибки отсутствуют. Есть у кого то мысли, в чем трабл?

Comment: Срабатывает, но только на первом. Поменяйте id - itemIcon на class -  itemIcon и обработчик вешайте на класс обектов $('.itemIcon')

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось, так как Вы описали ;)